# Scheduler Job Package of SugarCRM CE 6.5 - Can it be intsalled in SugarCRM 7.x PRO?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created a package in SugarCRM CE 6.5 for the scheduler job installation. 
It is successfully installed in CE but will the same package be installed and work in SugarCRM 7 Pro?

Comment: That is tough to answer w/o knowing more. However, I'd anticipate that it will not even install until you edit the manifest.php file in your package to accept 7.x for the version. Even then you may get through the installer, but it may still not work. Also, Sugar Pro offers the built in scheduler already. Perhaps it can do what your package does for you?